# How can I replace a character with a new bullet point

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

If I copy and paste a PDF with bullet points into Word, Word no longer detects the bullet points

I created a Word document, added some bullets and printed to PDF and the result is

[image]

I then copy and paste the text from the PDF into Word, and I get

[image]

I understand that it no longer see's the black circles as bullet points

I don't see any options for a magic paste in Word

My question therefore is, is there something like a find and replace operation that will convert the black circles into bullet points, so I end up with something like the first picture in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the bullet and the spaces that follow, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, paste the copied item on the Find what box.
2. On the Replace with box, insert a space.
3. Click More. Put your cursor on Replace with box. Click Format. Select Style.
4. On the Replace Style window, select List Bullet. Click OK.

[image]

5. Set Search to `All`. The image below shows how the Find and Replace will look like. Click Replace All.

[image]

**Caveat:** A space is inserted before `One`, `Two` and `Three`.

Comment: Word fails to find any bullet characters using this method. "We made 0 replacements."

Comment: @user43432 Read the question and the answer. It is not supposed to find bullets. But to replace what was copied from a pdf document to MS Word with a bullet.